# Закрытие гамбургера при клике на ссылку HTML

Tags: html

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на любую ссылку из этого меню, гамбургер закрывался обратно. Вот что я сделал на данный момент

```js
$(function() {
  $("a[href^='#']").click(function() {
    var _href = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(_href).offset().top + "px"
    });
    $('.toggler').prop("checked", false);
    return true;
  });
});

$('a[data-target^="anchor"]').on('click', function() {
  $('.hamburger-toggler').toggler('hide');
  $a = $($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
});
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: rgba(64, 41, 176, 0.75);
  --overlay-color: linear-gradient(rgba(64, 41, 176, 0.85), rgba(118, 33, 192, 0.85));
  --menu-speed: 0.75s;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.menu-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 15%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 100%), #F7B11E;
  background-blend-mode: soft-light, normal;
  border: 0.871287px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 4.35644px 4.35644px 8.71287px #A6ABBD;
  border-radius: 5.80858px;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #303234;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div:before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger>div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: inherit;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div:after {
  top: 6px;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked+.hamburger>div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked+.hamburger>div:before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked+.hamburger>div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover+.hamburger>div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked~.menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked~.menu>div {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: var(--menu-speed);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked~.menu>div>div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div {
  background: var(--overlay-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vw;
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div>ul>li>a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="ссылка">Кнопка</a></li>
          <li><a href="ссылка">Кнопка</a></li>
          <li><a href="ссылка">Кнопка</a></li>
          <li><a href="ссылка">Кнопка</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

раз уж условие появление меню это установка `input.checkbox` в значение `true`, то просто пойдите от обратного и поставьте его в значение `false` чтобы меню закрылось

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.hamburger-off').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function offMenu() {
    document.querySelector('.toggler').checked = false;
  })
})


$(function() {
  $("a[href^='#']").click(function() {
    var _href = $(this);
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(_href).offset().top + "px"
    });
    $('.toggler').prop("checked", false);
    return true;
  });
});

$('a[data-target^="anchor"]').on('click', function() {
  $('.hamburger-toggler').toggler('hide');
  $a = $($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
});
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: rgba(64, 41, 176, 0.75);
  --overlay-color: linear-gradient(rgba(64, 41, 176, 0.85), rgba(118, 33, 192, 0.85));
  --menu-speed: 0.75s;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.menu-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 15%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 100%), #F7B11E;
  background-blend-mode: soft-light, normal;
  border: 0.871287px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 4.35644px 4.35644px 8.71287px #A6ABBD;
  border-radius: 5.80858px;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #303234;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div:before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger>div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: inherit;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div:after {
  top: 6px;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked+.hamburger>div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked+.hamburger>div:before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked+.hamburger>div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover+.hamburger>div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked~.menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked~.menu>div {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: var(--menu-speed);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked~.menu>div>div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div {
  background: var(--overlay-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vw;
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div>ul>li>a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li class="hamburger-off"><a href="#">Кнопка</a></li>
          <li class="hamburger-off"><a href="#">Кнопка</a></li>
          <li class="hamburger-off"><a href="#">Кнопка</a></li>
          <li class="hamburger-off"><a href="#">Кнопка</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' хм. действительно

Comment: @Sevastopol' нашел (¬‿¬)